# Fetching JSON data using PHP from Google geocode API

Tags: php, json, api, google-maps

The first error I get is `"Call to undefined function get_file_contents() on line 18"`, I've tried to define get_file_contents() in the beginning of the file. The error dissappears, but nothing is displayed from `echo $lat;`

```
<?php 
    require_once('../db.php');
    $api_key = "somekey";
    $sqlQuery = mysql_query("SELECT `County` FROM `table`"); 



    /* Fetch county */ 
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sqlQuery))  { 
        $countyArr = $rows['County']; 

        /* Call google API and save coordinates for each county */ 
        $json = get_file_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$countyArr.",+CA&key=".$api_key."");
        $obj = json_decode($json);
        if ($obj->status == "OK") {
            $lat = $obj->results->location->lat;
            $lng = $obj->results->location->lng;

            echo $lat;
        }
    }
?>
```

This is the API I'm using:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key

*Edit:*
The error may be caused by php.ini settings on Godaddy's server for shared hosting. I tried to add `"allow_url_fopen = On"` in the php.ini I found in the root folder, although it still doesn't work.

Comment: file_get_contents is the name of the function, not get_file_contetns

Comment: `file_get_contents` is a correct function name.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

require_once('../db.php');

$api_key = "somekey";

$sqlQuery = mysql_query("SELECT `County` FROM `table`"); 



/* Fetch county */ 

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sqlQuery))  { 

    $countyArr = $rows['County']; 



    /* Call google API and save coordinates for each county */ 

    $json = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$countyArr.",+CA&key=".$api_key."");

    $obj = json_decode($json);



    if ($obj->status == "OK") {

        $lat = $obj->results->location->lat;
        $lng = $obj->results->location->lng;

        echo $lat;




    }

}

?>
try file_get_contents this function
```